# Selenium Python not clicking on object

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a button to be clicked in my python with selenium script and it is not working at all.

This is the HTML code

```html
<button aria-label="Apply to Digital Marketing Leader on company website" id="ember161" class="jobs-apply-button artdeco-button artdeco-button--icon-right artdeco-button--3 artdeco-button--primary ember-view" data-control-name="shareProfileThenExternalApplyControl">  <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="link-external" class="artdeco-button__icon" size="small"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" data-supported-dps="16x16" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="16" height="16" focusable="false">
  <path d="M15 1v6h-2V4.41L7.41 10 6 8.59 11.59 3H9V1zm-4 10a1 1 0 01-1 1H5a1 1 0 01-1-1V6a1 1 0 011-1h2V3H5a3 3 0 00-3 3v5a3 3 0 003 3h5a3 3 0 003-3V9h-2z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>

<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    Apply
</span></button>
```

This is the xpath and the action I'm using to try to clicked

```py
apply_btn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Apply")]')
apply_btn.click()
```

And this is the error message I'm getting:

```py
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

I'm pretty new to all this so if anyone can help me figure this out and fix it I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Use `find_element_by_xpath` instead of `find_elements_by_xpath`, since find elements returns a list not an element, or you can keep it as is and just call click on index 0 `apply_btn[0].click()`

Answer (score 0):

The method `find_elements_by_xpath` (notice *"elements"*) returns a **list of elements** that satisfy the given XPath. If you want to return only a **single element** (the first element that satisfies the XPath) instead of a list of elements, `find_element_by_xpath` (notice *"element"*) could be used.

```
apply_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Apply")]')
```